# Adding any number of integers in spring boot application using postman

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to add any number of integers in spring boot application. I have made application which can add two integers but i want to add any number of integers.Below is the code for two integers. Input and output is given using postman.
My Helloworld.java controller class :-

```
 package com.example.HelloWorld.controller;

import com.example.HelloWorld.model.Numbers;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
 @RestController
public class HelloWorldController
 {

  @PostMapping(path = "/addition", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
  public int addMember(@RequestBody Numbers number) {
    //code


    int num = number.getNumber_One();
    int numTwo = number.getNumber_Two();
    System.out.println("NUMBERs :: "+ num + " "+ numTwo);
    return num+numTwo;



  }

}

Numbers.java POJO is 

package com.example.HelloWorld.model;

public class Numbers {
public int number_One;
public int number_Two;

public int getNumber_One() {
    return number_One;
}

public void setNumber_One(int number_One) {
    this.number_One = number_One;
}

public int getNumber_Two() {
    return number_Two;
}

public void setNumber_Two(int number_Two) {
    this.number_Two = number_Two;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you change your POJO like:

```java
public class Numbers {

    private List<Integer> numbers;

    public List<Integer> getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public void setNumbers(List<Integer> numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }
}
```

And you can send a JSON request like:

```json
{
    "numbers": [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

Your controller, if you want to sum the numbers, could look like:

```java
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @PostMapping("/addition")
    public int addMember(@RequestBody Numbers numbers) {
        return numbers.getNumbers().stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry i am new here could you please explain me or give reference which topic should i read to get the meaning of "        return numbers.getNumbers().stream().reduce(0, Integer::sum);"

Comment: Sure, search for java stream api